# React minified error #31: "Objects are not valid as a React child" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a react error when browsing my application on IE 11. The specific problem is React minified **error #31**:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner}).

It might be related to babel not transpiling our indexjs correctly on IE 11.

Comment: babel does not transpile code on the browser. It does it only once on your machine and the same code is loaded in all browsers.

Comment: facing the same issue, is this working for you now ?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are missing 'babel-polyfill'.
Require it in the very beginning itself.
You might want to  check  these link
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/213

Answer (score -2):

install plugin babel-polyfill in your app.

```
npm install --save @babel/polyfill
```

include the polyfill you need using *require* at the top of the entry point to your application. 
(*app.js* or *index.js*)

```
require("babel-polyfill");
```

Comment: installing this package does not fix the issue and using require/import gives a compile error.